# Power Apps: How do I show/hide a button based on a Text Input's length of its value?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

In Power Apps, I would like to hide a button unless a specific Text Input has a value of at least one character.

**Example**:

- if TextInputOne has no value, ButtonOne will be hidden
- if TextInputOne's value is at least one character, ButtonOne will be displayed

I have just started using Power Apps today so I have not tried much. Therefore, I thank you all in advance for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below formula in **Visible** property of Button control:

```
Len(TextInputOne.Text)
```

[image]

**Documentation**: [Len function in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-len)

Comment: Thank you Ganesh!